# Showing that an integral exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to prove that  $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}xe^{-xt}dx$ exists, given that $x≥0$. I have set it equal to 
$$\lim\limits_{a \to\infty}\displaystyle \int_0^{a}xe^{-xt}\,dx$$ and know to use the comparison test next. However whatever I compared it to, it wasn't always less than, it varied on if $x$ was less than $1$. I know I need to find something bigger than it that converges, but I am unsure on what!

Comment: Can you just use integration by parts?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are trying to prove this using the dominated convergence theorem? It is easy enough to find the $\int_0^a x e^{-xt}\,dx$ explicitly using integration by parts.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "comparison test" in this context?

Comment: @Paul i can do so, however was wondering how I could do it specifically using the comparison test.

Comment: Just use $e^{-xt/2}$.

Comment: But that is not bigger than $xe^{-xt}$ for all $x$?

Comment: You don't need it to be true for all $x$.  You just need to be true for all $x$ greater than some $x_0$, which is the case here.